# Why does my React page scrolls every time I'm typing inside an input?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a form in React, and every time I'm typing anything inside an input the page scrolls to the top. Does anyone have a solution to this problem? This my code:

```
const [fullName, setFullName] = useState()
const handleFullName = e => setFullName(e.target.value)

return (
    <Input
        id="fullName"
        onChange={handleFullName}
        value={fullName}
    />
)
```

Thanks for your answers!

EDIT:

From what I see it comes from the setState function, and the bug appears only on Chrome

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obviously somewhere else, maybe there is a rerender, with that rerender, the page goes back to its initial position.
Is there another state that "listen" to this state ?

Comment: This page is rendered within the router (react-router-dom v6), maybe it comes from this? But I have the same code on another project and it's not doing this

Answer (score 0):

Provide more details please where are you getting that Input and Form Components from? Next? Material? I see they are not native...

Nothing you are doing there makes the code scroll
Please check this stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rdklvk

Comment: I'm getting these components from my own components library [here](https://documentation-components-react.vercel.app/components/input). It's just some native inputs which have been styled with styled-components. You can check the full code for inputs components [here](https://github.com/JulSeb42/react-library/blob/master/src/components/Input.js). And yes I didn't add anything which could make the page scroll, is it maybe a bug with React?